# How to call a SOAP webservice with a simple String (xml in string format) SOAPCLIENT PHP

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

instead of sending an array of parameters I would just like to send an xml as a string

Instead of

```
$response = $client->__soapCall("Quote", array($xml));
```

Like so

```
 $response = $client->__soapCall("Quote", $xml);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't. Atleast not with the PHP SoapClient https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Why would you even want to though? Just send the array with only the xml.